# curl docker works on local machine but not on server

Tags: docker, curl

I have created a docker-compose file to run my nodejs server, then i deployed it on my server
when I curl (or send a GET request with postman) the ip adress of my server with the specific port, it works (http://mywebsite:5000 )

But when I curl the same adress FROM MY SERVER (with ssh) : curl http://mywebsite:5000 I get:
curl: (7) Failed to connect to http://mywebsite.com:5000; connection refused

Any help please?
Thank you.

Comment: We need more information to help you. Can you provide the docker-compose.yml file ? Did you open the port in the firewall ? Is the DNS record ok ?

Comment: Docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

services:
  ui:
    image: node:latest
    container_name: nextjs
    command: bash -c "npm install && npm run build && npm run start" 
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app/
      - /usr/app/node_modules
      - /usr/app/.next
    working_dir: /usr/app/
    ports:
      - "5000:3000"

Comment: the curl works from my personal machine, it doesn't work only on the server, so i can't call the service from other applications deployed on the server

Answer (score 1):

Your server probably has proxy or firewall restrictions and it's blocking your requesting for your mywebsite domain, or the 5000 port or both

Comment: But i can curl it from my personal machine,

Comment: yes, but firewalls have inbound and outbound rules
let's say your problem really is firewall rules
and those rules say that your server accepts requesting from outside through port 5000 but it also says that nothing can go out of your server through the same port
When you call mywebsite:5000 inside your server it would be blocked.
I'm not a network expert, just trying to help
Can you get any response curl(ing) HTTP://localhost:5000 from your server?